# What is the difference between the terms "memory", "main memory", "RAM", "Memory bank" and "Memory Module"

Tags: memory, motherboard, computer-architecture

What is the difference in the followoing words? They seem to all be interchangable.

Memory, Main memory, RAM, Memory bank, Memory Module.

Correct me if I'm wrong but my understanding is memory is a very general term, for example anywhere data can be stored can be considered memory (except registers). Main memory refers to the memory that typically sits between HDD and CPU and is RAM. RAM is a technology for main memory, in the sense that it allows for random reads and writes. Memory bank is the physical location on the motherboard where the main memory goes. Memory module is a physical piece of main memory (such as those strips you can buy from the store). Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

**Memory** - a broad term including all type of memory.  This includes RAM, ROM, flash, etc.

**RAM** - Random Access Memory.   A random-access device allows stored data to be accessed directly in any random order.  Today, random-access memory takes the form of integrated circuits. Strictly speaking, modern types of DRAM are not random access, as data is read in bursts, although the name DRAM / RAM has stuck. However, many types of SRAM, ROM, OTP, and NOR flash are still random access even in a strict sense. RAM is normally associated with volatile types of memory (such as DRAM memory modules), where its stored information is lost if the power is removed. Many other types of non-volatile memory are RAM as well, including most types of ROM and a type of flash memory called NOR-Flash. The first RAM modules to come into the market were created in 1951 and were sold until the late 1960s and early 1970s.

**Memory Bank** - A memory bank is a logical unit of storage in electronics, which is hardware dependent. In a computer the memory bank may be determined by the memory access controller along with physical organization of the hardware memory slots.

**Memory Module** - A broad term used to refer to a series of dynamic random access memory integrated circuits modules mounted on a printed circuit board and designed for use in personal computers, workstations and servers.

Comment: I still don't see the difference between memory bank and memory module.

Comment: a memory bank contains memory modules

Comment: oh so is it the memory bank is the slots on the motherboard (i.e. the adapters) and the modules is what you put in them? or not really?

Comment: A memory bank can consist of 1, some, or all the slots, so yes.

Comment: ok finally I see what you're saying. Basically it's a partition of the memory.

Comment: You missed out main memory